# How would I align two outputs in Python 3?

Tags: python, vertical-alignment

How do I align two different outputs to be side-by-side in Python 3?

input:

```
def Pokemon_Output(user_pkmn):

print("ID#",pkmn[user_pkmn][0])
print("Name:",pkmn[user_pkmn][1])
print("Type 1:",pkmn[user_pkmn][2])`
print("Type 2:",pkmn[user_pkmn][3])
print("Total:",pkmn[user_pkmn][4])
print("HP:",pkmn[user_pkmn][5])
print("Attack:",pkmn[user_pkmn][6])
print("Defense:",pkmn[user_pkmn][7])
print("Sp. Atk:",pkmn[user_pkmn][8])
print("Sp. Def:",pkmn[user_pkmn][9])
print("Speed:",pkmn[user_pkmn][10])
print("Legendary:",pkmn[user_pkmn][12])

def Second_Pokemon_Output(second_user_pkmn):
print("ID#",pkmn[second_user_pkmn][0])
print("Name:",pkmn[second_user_pkmn][1])
print("Type 1:",pkmn[second_user_pkmn][2])
print("Type 2:",pkmn[second_user_pkmn][3])
print("Total:",pkmn[second_user_pkmn][4])
print("HP:",pkmn[second_user_pkmn][5])
print("Attack:",pkmn[second_user_pkmn][6])
print("Defense:",pkmn[second_user_pkmn][7])
print("Sp. Atk:",pkmn[second_user_pkmn][8])
print("Sp. Def:",pkmn[second_user_pkmn][9])
print("Speed:",pkmn[second_user_pkmn][10])
print("Legendary:",pkmn[second_user_pkmn][12])
```

current output:

```
ID# 4
Name: Charmander
Type 1: Fire
Type 2:
Total: 309
HP: 39
Attack: 52
Defense: 43
Sp. Atk: 60
Sp. Def: 50
Speed: 65
Legendary: Not Legendary

ID# 1
Name: Bulbasaur
Type 1: Grass
Type 2: Poison
Total: 318
HP: 45
Attack: 49
Defense: 49
Sp. Atk: 65
Sp. Def: 65
Speed: 45
Legendary: Not Legendary
```

My idea was to align both outputs to side by side regardless of what the inputs were. Something like this:

```
ID# 4                       ID# 1
Name: Charmander            Name: Bulbasaur
Type 1: Fire                Type 1: Grass
Type 2:                     Type 2: Poison
Total: 309                  Total: 318
HP: 39                      HP: 45
Attack: 52                  Attack: 49
Defense: 43                 Defense: 49
Sp. Atk: 60                 Sp. Atk: 65
Sp. Def: 50                 Sp. Def: 65
Speed: 65                   Speed: 45
Legendary: Not Legendary    Legendary: Not Legendary
```

After that I was planning on doing some kind of analysis comparing the stats between the two Pokemon, but really what I'm trying to do is just align everything. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Opinion corner: as soon as your output needs become more sophisticated than "print text on sequential rows", it's time to switch to a GUI. You'd be better off with a window with two text areas, than trying to convince a console to print multiple columns.

Comment: `format` function offers all you need for this. Your question is probably a duplicate though. Searching for  "formatting output" should give a lot of hits on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Kevin Neighbour opinion corner: I can imagine that one would still be ok with a console output even for some simple tables. format or f-strings used with space filled minimum length variables would do. I find the two separate functions with all those print statements more debatable. One with two dataframes as parameters would be the first step in the (imo) right direction

Comment: @SpghttCd I had a ton of formatted console output as you describe... an example convoluted base format string was `"%-9s %-{}s %8.4f%% (%{}i/%{}i)"` which was passed to `.format` after calculating the proper lengths for the variable fields, then to `%` to populate with the data. Boom, automatically sized tables that are variable width and it takes ~15 LOC in a function that got reused a dozen times. Could I have writen a GUI for the tool? Sure, but given most of the output ended up in the bug tracker, which only supported monospaced text: it produced tables which can be directly copy pasted.

Answer (score 1):

You have to print both in one function.

Something like this is what you need:

```
def Pokemon_Output(first_pkmn, second_pkmn):
    column1 = "ID#" + pkmn[user_pkmn][0]
    column2 = "ID#" + pkmn[second_user_pkmn][0]
    print_line(column1, column2)
    column1 = "Name:" + pkmn[user_pkmn][1]
    column2 = "Name:" + pkmn[second_user_pkmn][1]
    print_line(column1, column2)
    .
    .
    .

def print_line(column1, column2):   
    print('{:<25s}{:<25s}'.format(column1, column2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to use the property names of your dataset as the index of a pandas dataframe `pkmn`, like:

```
                    user1           user2
ID                      4               1
Name           Charmander       Bulbasaur                   
Type 1               Fire           Grass                   
Type 2                NaN          Poison                   
Total                 309             318                   
HP                     39              45                   
Attack                 52              49                   
Defense                43              49                   
Sp. Atk                60              65                   
Sp. Def                50              65                   
Speed                  65              45                   
Legendary   Not Legendary   Not Legendary
```

This done, your print function shrinks down to

```
print(df.loc[:, users])
```

with e.g.

```
users = ['user1', 'user2']
```